# Android: Best option for reading numbers from image with Tesseract or other api

Tags: android, ocr

Recently, I made a application for reading images with OCR tesseract. However, the problem is that the accuracy for reading numbers is only about 60%. Are there any option for better api for reading numbers? Or should I stick with tesseract? I'm actually new to OCR development and have a hard time with it.

[image]

Comment: Please share with us examples of the images you use for recognition.

Comment: I've added the image above. I want to retreive the numbers from the oriental lucky ticket. Are there any easy tutorial or sample that a noob like me can learn ?

Comment: there is ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/, but it's not free

Comment: here is an app for ocr test based on tesseract found in market https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr

Comment: Thank you for the comments. But what I want to do is to make a OCR tesseract based app for android.  And I want to know how to improve the accuracy through training.

Comment: here is some information about training in tesseract https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3 and based on this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/OXgEGOJc41Y you need to port all training tools to android.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! The problem  with me is I'm using windows and eclipse,and I have no further knowledge about linux. Is it possible to port the training tools easily? Or are there some sample or a easy step by step tutorial if possible? I've been coding for a couple of years but perhaps, I lack the knowledge?